# Dell Inspiron mini 10v hand while playing hd video

Tags: laptop, memory, performance, dell-inspiron, video-streaming

I have the problem of Dell Inspiron mini 10v while playing hd video.

So recently i have upgraded the RAM to 2 GB DDR2

but still there is no improvement while playing HD video, both sound n video are running slowly.. take 2 seconds for every frame

Any suggestion to fix this issue, like video memory upgrade ??? or tuning up the laptop ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

More memory won't make a difference here, it's the CPU and integrated GPU that are causing the problem. Try using Media Player Classic Home Cinema and Core AVC codecs. This combination is meant to work wonders for HD video on the Atom range of processors. Apparently, it even handles 1080p video very well.